# Recover a new (deleted) Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I tried to create a new Gmail account today for a blog, but was having trouble with the name. I deleted it and now it won't let me re-create an account with the same name. How can I recover the Gmail account I started and deleted today?

Answer (score 6):

From the following Google Accounts Help page:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en

> ### Recover a recently deleted Google Account
>
> If you [deleted your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046), you have a short amount of time to try to recover it. You can then sign in with this account to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google products.
>
> To see if you can recover your account:
>
> 1. Visit the [password assistance](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/) page.
> 2. Select **I'm having other problems signing in**.
> 3. Follow the steps on the screen to verify your identity and attempt to restore your account.